# How to write SQL with filter for one value in whole table?

Tags: sql

I have table with these values:

```
ID  SomeId  SomeResult
1   100     Ok
2   100     Ok
3   101     Ok
4   101     Error
```

How to write SQL expresion to get just one value:

```
1   100 Ok
```

Here "SomeResult" for "SomeId" was "Error" then we shouldn't include this "SomeId"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for the IDs that are not ok, and the exclude them:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT SomeId, SomeResult
FROM t
WHERE SomeId NOT IN (
    SELECT SomeId 
    FROM t 
    WHERE SomeResult <> 'OK'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `group by` and `having`.  I think this is the logic you want:

```
select someid
from t
group by someid
having min(someresult) = max(someresult) and
       min(someresult) = 'OK';
```

Or, if there are more than two values, you might want:

```
having sum(case when someresult like '%Error%' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

This counts the number of errors, and the `= 0` only returns ids with no errors.

Answer (score 0):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select min(t.ID) ID, SomeId, 'Ok' SomeResult
from tablename t
where t.SomeResult = 'Ok'
and not exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where SomeId = t.SomeId and SomeResult = 'Error'
)
group by t.SomeId;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rKeomXCijnKgBnTAyCaYyF/0).
Results:

```
| ID  | SomeId | SomeResult |
| --- | ------ | ---------- |
| 1   | 100    | Ok         |
```